# Sendmail virtual address

Tags: centos, virtualhost, sendmail

I'm trying to set up a new virtualuser with my Sendmail server. I've updated domaintable.db, generics-domains.db, sendmail.mc and restarted the sendmail process.

Mail is being returned with the error "550: relaying denied".

I've grepped for all files in /etc/mail that have the name of the working virtual domain, and made sure that every one of those files has been updated with the new virtual domain and user.  Made sure the databases are updated (grep finds binary matches). I can't figure out what I could possibly be missing.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual users live in /etc/mail/virtusertable (and its appropriate database). Prior to that, place the virtual domain in /etc/mail/local-host-names and restart sendmail.